# Spring tool suite bug

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Can anyone tell me exactly which version of Spring-tool-suite runs without any work-space configuration errors? I already tried 3 versions and all having same issues. I have jdk running smoothly in my machine.

Comment: Perhaps you should list the configuration problems you're having. I'd install the latest STS 3.8.1

Comment: It would be good to provide more details on this. What is the error that you see exactly? Can you provide steps how to reproduce this?